# LINQ in Entity Framework append onto DATETIME WHERE clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, lambda

I'm trying to build a WHERE clause during run time.  I have created a query with the initial WHERE clause:

```
var origSQL = (from ....
               join ...
               where ...
               select new { ... } );
```

and will be adding the following WHERE to origSQL:

```
var endDate = (from table1 in db.Table1
               join aliasTable1 in db.Table1 on table1.id equals aliasTable1.id
               where aliasTable1.anotherId  == anInputStr
               && (table1.field1 == aliasTable1.field1)
               select DbFunctions.TruncateTime(aliasTable1.endDate)).Max();
...
```

The endDate will need further refinement prior to attaching to the original WHERE, like:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherInputStr) && (anotherInputStr == "FOO"))
   endDate = endDate.Where ( a=> aliasTable1.GRADE == "F" );
```

On this, I get error:

```
DateTime does not contain a definition for Where accepting a first argument of type DateTime
```

So I removed the select portion from the initial endDate, figuring I can add it later:

```
var endDateCriteria = from table1 in db.Table1
               join aliasTable1 in db.Table1 on table1.id equals aliasTable1.id
               where aliasTable1.anotherId  == anInputStr
               && (table1.field1 == aliasTable1.field1)

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherInputStr) && (anotherInputStr == "FOO"))
   endDateCriteria = endDateCriteria .Where ( a=> aliasTable1.GRADE == "F" );
```

But the

```
.Where
```

is causing issue still. I need to append a bunch of these checks to be added onto this WHERE, to then be appended onto the original query, and can't locate the correct syntax.

**Added** This is originally a self-join.  The original dynamic SQL looks likes this

```
origSQL := ' AND table1.endDate = (
                 SELECT MAX(endDate)
                 FROM table1 aliasTable1   
                 WHERE aliasTable1.ID = table1.ID)
```

And I am trying to append additional WHERE clauses onto this one, which then in its entirety will be appended onto the main query.  I don't know the syntax for this.

Comment: Can you show what is the data type of `endDateCriteria ` ?

Comment: Your `.Max()` ensures that you don't return Enumerable or Queryable, but rather a single date, on which you cannot perform `Where()` or similar linq functions. Possible solutions are: select multiple values instead of only the date, or instead of `.Max();` try `ToList();` then perform the checking.

Comment: What entity has this `GRADE` property? In your second query, you didn't post what you are selecting (you must always select something).

Comment: @Jacky: it's a DateTime type being returned from the select clause.

Comment: @Andrew: it is another field in the (aliased) self-joined table table1, but it is a conditional WHERE to be included only if <predicate> is met.

Comment: If you are joining a table with itself by primary key, what is `table1.field1 == aliasTable1.field1` for? As I said above, you need to end your query with a select, which one are you using? Or is that non-building code?

Comment: @Andrew - the 1st listed endDate snippet with the **select** does compile, up to the point where I then try to add the predicated WHERE clause.  The 2nd attempt at endDateCriteria did not build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every query must have a select, which will define what your variable will hold. In your second example you have none, so that doesn't compile. You should do something like this:

```
var endDateCriteria = from table1 in db.Table1
                        join aliasTable1 in db.Table1 on table1.id equals aliasTable1.id
                        where aliasTable1.anotherId == anInputStr
                        && (table1.field1 == aliasTable1.field1)
                        select new { table1, aliasTable1 };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherInputStr) && (anotherInputStr == "FOO"))
    endDateCriteria = endDateCriteria.Where(q => q.aliasTable1.GRADE == "F");

if (somethingElse)
    endDateCriteria = endDateCriteria.Where(q => q.aliasTable1.field1 > value);

if (otherCondition)
    endDateCriteria = endDateCriteria.Where(q => q.table1.field2 != value2);

DateTime result = endDateCriteria.Max(q => q.aliasTable1.endDate).Date;
```

Here I'm storing in `endDateCriteria` both tables in an anonymous object, so I can later continue using both tables for my conditions, and in the end I get the maximum date. I don't see the need to use `TruncateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer with conditional mentioned in the comment by the original poster:

```
var endDates = (from table1 in db.Table1
               join table2 in db.Table2 on table1.id equals table2.id
               where table2.anotherId  == anInputStr
               && (table1.field1 == table2.field1);
if(YOUR CONDITION)
{
 endDates = endates.Where(e=> e.).Grade == "F")
}
var endate = from endates select DbFunctions.TruncateTime(table2.endDate)).Max();
```

You were originally operating on a single object (the Maximume table2.enddate) `.Where` acts on a collection.

```
var endDate = (from table1 in db.Table1
               join table2 in db.Table2 on table1.id equals table2.id
               where table2.anotherId  == anInputStr
               && (table1.field1 == table2.field1)
```

&& table(I don't know which table).Grade == "F"

```
               select DbFunctions.TruncateTime(table2.endDate)).Max();
```

Comment: I corrected to illustrate where Grade is to be derived if condition is met.  I have to append the clause conditionally, and haven't found the syntax.

Comment: That won't work, you need to select something and the following `.Where` will depend on that. Please check your syntax, which has many errors.